# My application does show toast message if network is not available

Tags: android

My application did not show toast message when network is  not available or disabled? I have inserted my code below, it doesn't seem to check to see if a connection is available. Please help me it works fine when a network is available but when I disable my network it did not show the error message, there was no other networks available.

```
if (position == 2)

{

    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)  
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connMgr  
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    android.net.NetworkInfo mobile1 =  
            connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (activeNetworkInfo == null) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "No   
                Active Network",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        if (activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                public  void onClick(View view) {
                    String pinemptycheck = pin.getText().toString();
                    String mobileemptycheck = mobile.getText().toString();
                    if  (pinemptycheck.trim().equals("")||  
                            (mobileemptycheck.trim().equals("")))
                    {


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Correct Information",  
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    } 


                    else
                    {

                        showProgress();
                        postLoginData();
                    }

                }
            });
        } else if  
        (activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,    "network is Connecting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)  
            .show();
        } else if (mobile1.isAvailable()) {

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new  
                    OnClickListener() {

                public  void onClick(View view) {

                    showProgress();

                    postLoginData();                                    

                }
            });
        } else if (!mobile1.isAvailable()) {

            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"No other Connection Found  
                    ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v)

                        {

                            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this," No other Connection Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });
        }}}
```

Comment: your code is too messy,Use Log & check that method call or not which you want.

Comment: just tell me   typemobile check which network?

Comment: what is diffrence in between this two lines

NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connMgr  
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();



NetworkInfo mobile1 =  
            connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

Comment: Can you put breakpoints and debug and see what conditions are getting satisfied?

Comment: is always go insite this conditoion if network not vaailable also go in this contion
  if (activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {

inside this if block and run application

Comment: either network disbale or not is go inside this condtion

 if (activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
 and run application

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you should check connection availability inside onClickListener instead above onClickListener.

Behind the reason is this suppose at the time network is present when onCreate call so its give true all the time.So Check connection available or not when you click the button.